# PIL cutting off image when rotating?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to rotate an image in python using PIL , however when rotating with PIL it keeps the original dimensions of the image. e.g. if I try to rotate it it gets cut off at the edges. The easiest way to explain this is by showing you :

Original : [image]

Output (after rotating 90 degrees) :
[image]

Is there a way in which I can rotate the image and then save the rotated version without the clipping using PIL? Or if this isn't possible using PIL what other ways would you recommend.

Comment: What is the code you used to generate the 2nd image?

Answer (score 5):

I'm unsure on what is the piece of code you are using, but I guess you are not using `expand=True` with `rotate()` function which actually expands the image to accommodate the rotated image. Please find the info here in the [Official Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate).

Below is the actual code which works for reference.

```
from PIL import Image

# open image
image=Image.open('sample.jpg')

# rotate image
image=image.rotate(90, expand=True)

# save image
image.save('newsample.jpg')
```